# dcast without ID variables

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

In the "An Introduction to reshape2" package Sean C. Anderson presents the following example.

He uses the airquality data and renames the column names

```
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
```

The data look like

```
#   ozone solar.r wind temp month day
# 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

Then he melts them by

```
aql <- melt(airquality, id.vars = c("month", "day"))
```

to get

```
#   month day variable value
# 1     5   1    ozone    41
# 2     5   2    ozone    36
# 3     5   3    ozone    12
# 4     5   4    ozone    18
# 5     5   5    ozone    NA
# 6     5   6    ozone    28
```

Finally he gets the original one (different column order) by

```
aqw <- dcast(aql, month + day ~ variable)
```

## My Quesiton

Assume now that we do not have ID variables (i.e. month and day) and have melted the data as follows

```
aql <- melt(airquality)
```

which look like

```
#   variable value
# 1    ozone    41
# 2    ozone    36
# 3    ozone    12
# 4    ozone    18
# 5    ozone    NA
# 6    ozone    28
```

My question is how can I get the original ones? The original ones would correspond to

```
#   ozone solar.r wind temp 
# 1    41     190  7.4   67 
# 2    36     118  8.0   72 
# 3    12     149 12.6   74
# 4    18     313 11.5   62 
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit "solutions" into your original question. If you have a different/better solution, you should add your answer below. Otherwise, just accept the one you think is best.

Comment: If you're using data.table, the tutorial for its reshaping tools is here: https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html Your question nowhere mentions data.table apart from the tag, though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is `unstack`

```
out <- unstack(aql,value~variable)
head(out)
#   ozone solar.r wind temp month day
#1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
#5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

As the question is about `dcast`, we can create a sequence column and then use `dcast`

```
aql$indx <- with(aql, ave(seq_along(variable), variable, FUN=seq_along))
out1 <- dcast(aql, indx~variable, value.var='value')[,-1]
head(out1)
#   ozone solar.r wind temp month day
#1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
#5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

If you are using `data.table`, the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5` also has `dcast` function.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(aql)[, indx:=1:.N, variable]
 dcast(aql, indx~variable, value.var='value')[,-1]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I wanted to use it in a data.table object (see Update up)

Comment: @conighion Updated the post with the data.table option.  Make sure to install the devel version.

Answer (score 2):

One option using `split`,

```
out <- data.frame(sapply(split(aql, aql$variable), `[[`, 2))
```

Here, the data is split by the `variable` column, then the second column of each group is combined back into a data frame (the `[[` function with the argument `2` is passed to `sapply`)

```
head(out)
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```